# SQL Server Cluster Install on Mount Point

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I am trying to install a `Failover` cluster instance and I ran into the following issue:

> Updating permission setting for folder 'C:\ClusterStorage\PRODSQL\SQLData\MSSQL14.PRODSQL\MSSQL\DATA' failed. The folder permission setting were supposed to be set to 'D:P(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;FA;;;CO)(A;OICI;FA;;;S-1-5-80-3017142923-4147168812-3961353769-1417247779-429559477)'.

*PRODSQL* is clustered shared storage (*CSV*) and it is mounted to `C:\ClusterStorage`.

The service account is admin account.

Created sub folder - `SQLData` on the mount point as per Microsoft recommendation.

Please advice if anyone has seen this issue.

Comment: I suspect permissions are not properly granted on the ***volume*** (which requires a different approach than granting permissions to a *folder*) prior to the install.  Check [my answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/182750/39083) for more information on this caveat to mount points.

Comment: Hello John, I checked your answer in the other thread. In this case, we are using sub folder <<SQLData>> and using that folder as base for sql install. we do not have any files in mount point drive( C\clusterstorage\prodsql) except hidden files - system volume information and recycle bin.

Comment: Don't know if you ran across [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/202516/39083) or not, but maybe it will provide some relevance for your issue.